# Vim E194: No alternate file name to substitute for '#'

Tags: vim, ctrlp

I am using ctrlp.vim plugin which is essentially a file finder. I followed the installation steps as mentioned here:

http://kien.github.io/ctrlp.vim/#installation   (using git)

My plugin is working fine and as expected but on starting vim I get following error:

```
Error detected while processing FuncUndefined Auto commands for "*":
E194: No alternate file name to substitute for '#': runtime autoload/ctrlp#utils#cachedir.vim
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

On removing `set runtimepath^=~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim` from my vimrc the error goes away but obviously even my plugin stops working which is not desired.

Please help.

Comment: Why `set runtimepath^=~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim` in the first place?

Comment: followed the installation steps.  Check it here: http://kien.github.io/ctrlp.vim/#installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of that command is wrong: Instead of

```
runtime autoload/ctrlp#utils#cachedir.vim
```

it should be

```
runtime autoload/ctrlp/utils/cachedir.vim
```

The `#` separator is used when *calling* autoload functions, but `:runtime` requires a path, with path separators. In there, the special identifiers such as `#` and `%` are in effect, and that causes the error.

---

To fix that, find out from where this wrong command is issued.

```
:verbose autocmd FuncUndefined
```

is a good start.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found the culprit. I had - 
autocmd FuncUndefined * exe 'runtime autoload/' . expand('<afile>') . '.vim'  set in my vimrc. I guess i did that for some other plugin long ago which im no more using. Commenting it solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with the Windows version of GVim 8.1 when trying to write a **[No Name]** buffer to a file name containing `#include`. Placing a `\` before each `#` in the filename works around the problem.

I thought it would conflict with the Windows convention of using backslashes to separate folders in file paths, but it didn't.